# MySQL/PHP fulltext search 1 word similarity

Tags: php, mysql, match, full-text-search

I have a client that wants to manage his SEO titles/descriptions for any page in the website, so I thought about making a module where he can enter the URL/TITLE/DESCRIPTION and the website will check if there is an entry for that page, and if there is, show it.

I have tried this:

```
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$q_seo = $conexio->query('SELECT modulseo.titol, modulseo.descripcio, MATCH(modulseo.url) AGAINST("'.$url.'") AS score FROM modulseo WHERE MATCH(modulseo.url) AGAINST("'.$url.'") ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,1');

if(mysql_num_rows($q_seo)>0)
{
    $d_seo = mysql_fetch_array($q_seo);

    $titol = $d_seo['titol'];
    $descripcio = $d_seo['descripcio'];

}
else
{
    $titol = 'default title';
    $descripcio = 'default description';
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, as I believe fulltext search only works with matching different words, not the similarity between 1 word and another, as the client can enter in the backend urls like:

- `http://www.domain.com/index.php`
- or `http://domain.com/index.php`
- or `http://www.domain.com/index.php?language=fr`
- or `http://domain.com/index.php?language=fr`
- etc..

and then the user of the website can access any of those urls, so there must be a way to match any of the urls with the any of the ones the client entenred in the backend.

Any clue about how to do this?

Comment: why don't you use `like` to make the search??

Answer (score 0):

Make the search with `LIKE %varible%` It's a slower query but it will work.

Your table engine had to be MyISAM or if you MySQL -v 5.6+ you can use InnoDB with a full text index

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+------------------------------+
| ids  | name | last_name                    |
+------+------+------------------------------+
|    0 | 0    | http://domain.com/index.php  |
|    1 | 0    | http://domain2.com/index.php |
|    2 | 0    | http://domain3.com/index.php |
+------+------+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test where last_name like '%http://domain.com/index.php%';
+------+------+-----------------------------+
| ids  | name | last_name                   |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
|    0 | 0    | http://domain.com/index.php |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Because if the administrator adds "`http://domain.com/index.php`" and the user is browsing "`http://www.domain.com/index.php`" it won't work, no?

Comment: I think it will work even if you make a search "%main%" it will find it

Comment: I edited my post, I even did search with `like '%//%';` and the result was display right

Comment: `mysql> select * from test where last_name like '%http://www.domain.com/index.php%';` Does not work, if you add the three 'www', that's why I wanted something that can match the closest similar string

Comment: There you go: http://pastebin.com/7uWpe5tB And it's not just the 'www.', but also if there is for example ?lang=fr after it, or something, that's why I wanted to match it against the most similar entry and LIKE can't work

Comment: @tebb can you explain better then what do you result should be? the search go word by word reading it to see if it match, when you use `like '%word%'`.  If you can't find make your query with `like` then you wont get it with anything, `like` is the 'slower' but the stronger text search in MySQL

Comment: if should find `http://domain.com/index.php` either if you search `http://domain.com/index.php`, `http://www.domain.com/index.php`, `http://domain.com/index.php?lang=fr`, `http://wwww.domain.com/index.php?lang=fr&page=1` etc...

Comment: then you need is a function, and it will take a lot because the function will need to make more that one search, can you change the design or the way to store the URL?

Comment: It's unlikely that the client will store the urls always the same way... maybe one he will put it with 'www.', one without, one with maybe the language var... who knows, clients are dumb XD

Comment: that's ok but when you make the sear be sure that you are not looking with 'WWW', I.E= 'www.google.com' you will search `where col like '%GOOGLE.COM%'`